# The Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: complex-analysis

To the people doing complex analysis, my question may perhaps look trivial.

The Kramers-Kronig relations tell us that for the real and imaginary parts of a complex function, that is analytic in the upper half-plane, the following holds:

$$
\Re f(z_0) =\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle \pi}  \mathcal{P}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\Im f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz\quad,\\
~\\
\Im f(z_0) =~-~\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle \pi}  \mathcal{P}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\Re f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz\quad.
$$

This ensues immediately from the Cauchy residue theorem with the contour chosen as shown on the image here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations

Now assume $\,f(z)\,$ is a real-valued function for real values of the argument $\,-\,$ like $\,\sin(z),~\exp(z)\,$ or any other complex function obtained by analytic continuation of a real one. So, for real $\,z\,$,  we arrive at: $\,\Im f(z) \equiv 0\,$. How can then the first integral remain nonzero, if the numerator on the RHS vanishes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you missed the part that said

> and vanishes like $1/|\omega|$ or faster as $|\omega| \rightarrow \infty$.

An analytic function on the upper half plane that is real on the real axis extends by the Schwarz reflection principle to an entire function.  If
it goes to $0$ as $|\omega| \to \infty$ in the upper half plane then it does so on the whole complex plane, and then by Liouville it is identically $0$.

Comment: Dear Robert, great thanks. Michael